# update row without considering space between two words

Tags: oracle, sql-update, sql-like

I am looking  to replace text in column `Text` with `format(A,B)` where text contains A and B only and ignoring spaces between A and B.

Here is test data

```
Id   Text
1    A    B               //should be replaced with format(A,B).
2    A         B          //should be replaced with format(A,B).
3    A B                  //should be replaced with format(A,B).
4    A 1    B             //shouldn't be replaced.
5    A   B 1              //should be replaced with format(A,B) 1.
```

I think I have to do something like

```
UPDATE test SET text = REPLACE(text, 'A[wild char for space]B', 'format(A,B)');
```

but how should I compare only for space? like % will compare everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle Regex fro this

```
UPDATE test SET text = REGEXP_REPLACE(testcol, '(A[:blank:]B)', 'format(A,B)')
```

## [Oracle Regex](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint:

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select 'A    B' col from dual union all
  3  select 'A              B' from dual union all
  4  select 'A B' from dual union all
  5  select 'AB' from dual union all
  6  select 'A 1  B' from dual union all
  7  select 'A   B 1' from dual
  8  )
  9  select regexp_replace(t.col, 'A[[:space:]]*B', 'format(A,B)') from t
 10  /

REGEXP_REPLACE(T.COL,'A[[:SPACE:]]*B','FORMAT(A,B)')                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
format(A,B)                                                                     
format(A,B)                                                                     
format(A,B)                                                                     
format(A,B)                                                                     
A 1  B                                                                          
format(A,B) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql for your scenario:

```
with tab(Id,Text) as 
(select 1,'A    B'   from dual union all --            //should be replaced with format(A,B).
select 2,'B         C' from dual union all --          //should be replaced with format(A,B).
select 3,'A B' from dual union all --                 //should be replaced with format(A,B).
select 4,'A 2    B' from dual union all --            //shouldn't be replaced.
select 5,'Y   Z 1' from dual) --             //should be replaced with format(A,B) 1.
select id, 
       text, 
       regexp_replace(text, '^\D\s+\D', 'format('||regexp_substr(text, '\D')||','||trim(regexp_substr(text, '\D+', 2))||')') format
  from tab;
```

output:

```
| ID |        TEXT |        FORMAT |
|----|-------------|---------------|
|  1 |      A    B |   format(A,B) |
|  2 | B         C |   format(B,C) |
|  3 |         A B |   format(A,B) |
|  4 |    A 2    B |      A 2    B |
|  5 |     Y   Z 1 | format(Y,Z) 1 |
```

And the update statement becomes

```
UPDATE test SET text = regexp_replace(text, '^\D\s+\D', 'format('||regexp_substr(text, '\D')||','||trim(regexp_substr(text, '\D+', 2))||')');
```